# Weird behavior from scipy.stats.probplot

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, data-science

In scipy's documentation they say:

The formula used for the theoretical quantiles (horizontal axis of the probability plot) is Filliben’s estimate:

> quantiles = dist.ppf(val), for 0.5**(1/n), for i = n
>
> val = (i - 0.3175) / (n + 0.365), for i = 2, ..., n-1
>
> 1 - 0.5**(1/n), for i = 1

where i
indicates the i-th ordered value and n
is the total number of values.

But when I actually plug in some numbers with it, it gives different values than the ones computed by the probplot function. For example:

```
np.random.seed(12)
n = np.random.randn(10) * 10
x, _ = stat.probplot(n, plot = plt)
```

-15.3472134 is the second value so I plug in

(2 - 0.3175) / (10 + 0.365) and it returns the quantile 0.162325 ( a number between 0 and 1) whereas the function plots it as -0.98494667 and labels the x axis theoretical quantiles. How is the -0.98494667 " theoretical quantile" computed from the actual quantile 0.162325?

Answer (score 0):

The values you get for 'val' are treated as probabilities. Using that probabilities you will get the quantiles using Percent Point Function(PPF) of the desired distribution(standard normal distribution in your case). The 'n' probabilities can also be obtained randomly from continuous uniform(0,1) distribution, but calculating the probabilities by the above method is one way. So scipy.stats.norm.ppf(0.162325)=-0.98494667.

For simplicity you can think of ppf as inverse of cdf.

'cdf' - For given x value, it returns the percentage of points/mass bellow that value.

'ppf' - For given probability, it returns the x value. It is similar to calculating the z-score.